# Why do my grades matter?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

I typically make A or A+ for Time and Offense, but I don't always make the best grades for Finesse. Furthermore, I get straight Ds when I run from fights during my all-night runs to level up Survival. How do my report grades affect me? Am I getting less EXP if my average grades are low?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Receiving high grades, you are getting some bonus experience, up to 40% (getting all grades A+).

Full breakdown of Finesse and Offense can be found [here](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/final-fantasy-15-report-card-finesse-time-offense-and-exp-bonus-explained-571483).

[image: Table of grade exp bonuses]

Since the Dec 22 2016 update, there are 3 new accessory items which reward additional AP for getting A+ grades in each category.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with this articles take on Finesse. I've found that missing attacks affects my Finesse grade. In my experience it's more about fluid fighting, breaking appendages and landing attacks consistently.

Comment: I disagree with the defense and stealth bits as well. I've gotten A+ for less than 4 parries and/or 6 blindsides...